# "point" to separate two texts in a TextView

Tags: android, textview, symbols

I want to separate two texts inside a TextView with a "point" like Youtube does (link to the image below). Is this an extra view or is it just a normal character?
[symbol to separate text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47QNv.png)

Comment: can you please provide a little more detail on what your input is and what you expect the output should be?

Comment: My text view should display the name of a bank then the "point"-symbol and then the balance of the bank account

Comment: I'm assuming that the `setText` property didn't work out for you. If my assumption is correct, I would like to see what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

The simplest is to use the Unicode for the dot symbol which you can get from somewhere like [here](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00B7).